# Do half-elves trance or sleep? Or both/either?

Tags: dnd-5e, racial-traits

Basic question from a newb: Do half-elves trance or sleep? Or both/either?

Comment: No worries.  What books do you have for the 5e system?  PHB?  DMG?  MM?  If none, you can download the [basic rules](http://media.wizards.com/2016/downloads/DND/PlayerBasicRulesV03.pdf) and the [SRD](http://media.wizards.com/2016/downloads/DND/SRD-OGL_V5.1.pdf) from the WoTC website, for free.  They have a lot of good basic information.

Comment: Yeah, I was working from a download (I assume not entirely legal) of the PHB.  Legal books ordered, anyone who might be checking....

Answer (score 8):

## Sleep

The Half Elves' entry in the PHB(p.39) does not give them the Trance trait. Thus, they sleep as normal for most races.

Comment: Thanks.  Wasn't sure if 'not mentioning it' was the same as 'not having it', I guess.

Comment: @Silemon Normally, it should be. They're pretty specific about their use of language.